# Can someone show me correct code to exit on strategy.position_avg_price if strategy.opentrades > 1

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I can't seem to get the below exit code to work. It's not placing a limit order on strategy.position_avg_price. I am using pyramiding in my strategy.

```
if long
    strategy.cancel("Long")
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, limit=close)
    strategy.exit("E_L1", "Long", profit = 100) 

if ta.crossover(high, strategy.position_avg_price) and strategy.opentrades > 1
    strategy.exit("E_L2", "Long", limit=strategy.position_avg_price)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this structure as a sample and rewrite your code based on this example:

```
//@version=5
strategy("Intrabar exit", overlay = true, calc_on_order_fills = true)

float stopSize   = input.float(5.0, "SL %", minval = 0.0) / 100.0
float profitSize = input.float(5.0, "TP %", minval = 0.0) / 100.0

if strategy.position_size == 0.0
    strategy.entry("Buy", strategy.long)

float stopLoss   = strategy.position_avg_price * (1.0 - stopSize)
float takeProfit = strategy.position_avg_price * (1.0 + profitSize)

strategy.exit("Exit", stop = stopLoss, limit = takeProfit)
```

if you have Pyramiding > 1 you can use this sample:

```
strategy("Close multiple ID demo", "test", overlay = true, pyramiding = 3)

switch strategy.opentrades
    0 => strategy.entry("A", strategy.long)
    1 => strategy.entry("B", strategy.long)
    2 => strategy.entry("C", strategy.long)
    3 => strategy.close_all()
```

Comment: Thank you Arman. But I do not want to use close_all because I need to exit via a limit order.